# How do I refer to an idiom in text?

Tags: idioms, writing-style

What is the best way to refer to the idiom "Keeping up with the Joneses"? I'm referencing the idiom in a paper, but not sure if I should include it in quotes or not in quotes, but italics.

Comment: Ask the editors of the publication in which your paper will be appearing for their style guide, or (if it is a student paper) the relevant departmental secretary of your educational institution.

Comment: I don't have access to those types of people, unfortunately. What would be the standard if this were for a personal paper submitted to an online blog?

Comment: That depends on whose blog it is. If it is your own blog, you are free to set and follow your own norms. If it is not your blog, I suggest you contact the individual(s) responsible for operating the blog you will be posting on and ask them if they will require your piece to adhere to a particular style guide. (FWIW: if given the choice, my own preference would be to enclose the idiom in single quote marks/inverted commas. I would reserve italics for the titles of books, journals etc., or for giving a particular word or phrase particular emphasis.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you are going to mention the idiom, just as you did in the question? Style guides, recognized authorities, and professional writers, editors, etc. prescribe and proscribe a number of approaches for mentioning letters, words, and phrases, as distinct from using them. While the use of quotation marks remains perhaps the most common, italics is suggested or preferred by many.

Where authorities recommend quotation marks, some suggest alternating from the main type you use (single or double) while others suggest using the same type.

http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/italics.htm

[http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use–mention_distinction](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction)

It's my experience that there may be a trend away from the most conventional (using the same number of quotes you use for enclosing dialogue) and toward more use of italics for this purpose.

Answer (score -2):

Quotes. Italics are for foreign language words in an English text. But you know, *caveat emptor*.

Comment: This answer ignores the convention of italics for the *use-mention distinction* and for identifying various technical terms.

Comment: I was being super economical with my reply. Thank you for pointing that out.